# Unable to Sum controls on continuous form

Tags: ms-access, vba

The following query gives correct results on a continuous form:

```
SELECT tblDisclosure.DBSInvoice, Sum(tblDisclosure.DBSFee) AS SumOfDBSFee, Count(tblDisclosure.ID) AS CountOfID, Sum([MyFee]+[Other]+[ExternalCheck]) AS Me
FROM tblDisclosure
GROUP BY tblDisclosure.DBSInvoice
HAVING (((tblDisclosure.DBSInvoice) Is Not Null));
```

On the form footer, I want to sum all DBS Invoices and Me controls, which I have Named 'DBSInv' and 'Me' . I am trying '=Sum([DBSInv])' and '=Sum([Me])' in Text Boxes but I get the result '#Error'.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because I was trying to use the NAME of the Text box, which I had created for convenience. If I name the texbox as SumOfDBSFee and make the Footer =Sum(SumOfCBSFee), it works.